# How is UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray implemented?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I want to mimic this style in code, more specifically in setSelected.

Does anybody have idea how do I do that assuming I'm using a custom cell.

Answer (score 2):

All cell selection styles are implemented by setting the `selectedBackgroundView` property of the cell. For the system blue and white ones, these are built-in views with blue and grey gradients. Setting the cell selection style to blue or grey just tells the cell to use one of those views as its selected background.

You can still use those styles for custom cells, assuming you've added all of your cell content to the content view.

You can create your own view (typically a stretchable image or custom drawing view) and set it as the selected background view for custom effects.

When the cell is selected, it will also tell any of its content view subviews (labels etc) to become highlighted, if they can. You can control how this looks by setting the `highlightedTextColor` on any labels.

You can achieve all this without needing to touch `setSelected`. It's all done by the base implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Found a post which fits exactly the `UIColor` implemented by Apple for `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray`:

```
UIColor* selectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:217.0/255.0 
                                         green:217.0/255.0 
                                          blue:217.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

To change things on selection, just implement you `setSelected:(BOOL)selected` method inside your custom `UIButton` extension. This can look like this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected{
    [super setSelected:selected];
    if( selected ){
        // change things here on highlight
    } else {
        // change things here on unhighlight
        NSLog(@"unselected");
    }    
}
```

to get into this mode, you should set your cell to `selected = YES`.

[Original post can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20958966/1141395)

Answer (score -1):

try with this one may be it helps you,

```
UIView *selectedBackgroundViewForCell = [UIView alloc]init];
[selectedBackgroundViewForCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
theCell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundViewForCell;
```

(or)

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedCellBackground.png"]] autorelease];
```

Comment: This doesn't set the color to the same as `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray` and doesn't show how a `UITableViewCell` is set to state selected.