# UIButton with UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray Selection Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, selection

I am trying to set the selected color for a UIButton to the color of 'UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray'; The problem is that the selection color of a UIButton cannot be set, only the image. Does anyone know how to make an image that is the exact color of a selected cell with UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray?

Comment: Are you creating the `UIButton` in code or a NIB/Storyboard?

Comment: I am creating a UIButton in code.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I can't seem to find the actual color programmatically but DigitalColor Meter (OSX APP) says the color is `217    217 217`

```
UIColor* selectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:217.0/255.0 
                                         green:217.0/255.0 
                                          blue:217.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Nice one, thats exactly the color of `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray`!

Comment: ...or just UIColor(white: 217.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

Comment: On iOS 13 this is UIColor.systemGray4!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIButton    *button =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame    =   CGRectMake(50, 50, 60, 20);
button.backgroundColor  =   [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orange.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question.

Comment: You can use color matcher for the desired color you want and put it in

Comment: I still don't think you have read the question. Selection color cannot be set.

Comment: You want the button color to be gray when selected??

Comment: Yes, I want the button color to be gray when selected.

Comment: Is your button on a cell?? and do you want to change the color when the button is selected or the cell??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37466/discussion-between-vaibhav-15-and-jpk)

Comment: No, button is not on a cell. I'm sorry, but I cannot continue this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `tintColor` property on a `UIButton`, the color is set on the highlighted state. So you could do this:

```
[button setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

However, `lightGrayColor` may not be the *exact* gray you're looking for. I'm not aware of a way to get reference to the exact selection-gray of a `UITableViewCell`. You might just have to play with `[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]` to get it like you want it.

**Also not that the `tintColor` property has different implications in iOS 7, so beware of that if you use this code.

Comment: I actually do need this for iOS7. And I am actually looking for the default selection gray color in iOS 7. I already tried this and I don't think it works in iOS 7 in any case. Thanks for your help.