# What's the RGB value for UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

What's the RGB value for UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray ? HEX value is appreciated as well.

Comment: Apple provide DigitalColor colorimeter to pick color from your screen. Applications -> Others -> DigitalColor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `Pixie` (an application available from Apple's Developer Center under "Downloads For Apple Developers" -> "Graphics Tools For Xcode"), and sampling a `UITableViewCell` displaying in the `selected` state with a `selectionStyle` property set to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray`, sRGB values came at `0.85` for `red`, `green`, and `blue`.

Multiplying by `255` (convert to RGB) yields `216.75` for each. Using the "RGB-to-HEX Conversion" tool at http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm and inputting `217` yields a hex value of `D9D9D9`.

Answer (score 2):

Found a post which fits exactly the `UIColor` implemented by Apple for `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray`:

```
UIColor* selectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:217.0/255.0 
                                         green:217.0/255.0 
                                          blue:217.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

[Original post can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20958966/1141395)

Comment: On iOS 13 this is UIColor.systemGray4!